# typescript mocha unit tests run twice

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

All my typescripts unit tests are under test/unit. All test files end with "test.ts". When I run using the following command it appears all tests are running twice. I think tests run for both .js and .ts even I specified extension for test files.

```
npx mocha -r ts-node/register -t 10000 --recursive "test/unit/**/*.test.ts"
```

And here is the output.

```
  CourseService
✓ find a course by a courseID should return a course
  StudentService
✓ should return student list
  CourseService
✓ find a course by a courseID should return a course
  StudentService
✓ should return student list
4 passing (48ms)
```

I want to run my integration test something like this.

```
    npx mocha -r ts-node/register -t 10000 --recursive "test/integraiton/**/*.test.ts"
```

Comment: you can specify the regex in your package.json to restrict it to use just .ts file. Something like `"jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[t]s?(x)"
    ]
  }`

Comment: On Mocha 7, you need to provide --extensions ts.
How about try to use ts-mocha (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mocha) instead ?